# django - is it a commonly accepted practice to combine form logic along with other references & variables in a view?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

This question may seem obvious, but I have been thrown for a loop the past few days.  The vast majority of tutorials and documentation I find on django-forms shows them as their own solitary views.

Take this example from django 1.6 official docs as a typical example, ['Using a form in a view'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

The problem I have is that I almost never dedicate a whole page or view just to one form.  I can't really `{% include %}` the form view due to context variables.  I also can't `{% extend %}` it without bringing in way to many items or reworking all of my templates and views.

**Is it a good practice to combine form logic along with other references and variables in the same view?**  I would just like to confirm that yes this is normal and acceptable or that no I am doing things unacceptably.  Off-hand there looks like some non DRY boilerplate if I do this in each view that needs a form.

There also appears to be some debate in the blogs & tutorials for form logic.  Its hard to tell whether modifying a CBV or using some good ol' FBV is preferred.  I just don't want to get any bad habits while I am still new and learning.

This is my currently "working" code for my view:

```
def home_page(request):
    all_sliders = Slider.objects.all()
    all_marketing = Marketing.objects.all()
    all_features = Feature.objects.all()
    skill_set = Skills.objects.all()

    #clunky way of adding the form...yes? no?
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if not request.POST.get('subject', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a subject.')
        if not request.POST.get('message', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a message.')
        if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
            errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
        if not errors:
            send_mail(
                request.POST['subject'],
                request.POST['message'],
                request.POST.get('email', 'noreply@mysite.com'),
                # email address where message is sent.
                ['email@mysite.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('frontpage/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    context = {'sliders': all_sliders, 'marketing': all_marketing,
               'feature': all_features, 'skills': skill_set, 
               #this is tied to my form logic
               'form': form, 'errors': errors,
               }
    return render(request, 'frontpage/home.html', context)
```

In closing, I don't want to use an add-on library.  I am learning django and want to learn it well before using libraries for basic things like forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with providing extra context/whatnot to a view with a form. In fact, it's pretty easy to do with CBVs. The [docs for the Generic FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) provide a good example of a contact form, and you can extend it to add your extra context by overriding the `get_context_data`. What you should not do is form validation in the view. Leave that to your form class in forms.py. Here's an example pieced together from the docs:

```
# forms.py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    email = forms.CharField()
    # Whatever fields you had.

    def clean(self):
        """This is where you should be checking for required
        fields and making sure the submitted data is safe."""
        pass

    def send_email(self):
        # send email using the self.cleaned_data dictionary
        send_mail(
            self.cleaned_data['subject'],
            self.cleaned_data['message'],
            self.cleaned_data.get('email', 'noreply@mysite.com'),
            ['email@mysite.com']
        )

# views.py
class HomePageFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'frontpage/home.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = 'frontpage/thanks/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['sliders'] = Slider.objects.all()
        context['marketing'] = Marketing.objects.all()
        context['feature'] = Feature.objects.all()
        context['skills'] = Skills.objects.all()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        return super(HomePageFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to combine form logic along with other
>   references and variables in the same view? I would just like to
>   confirm that yes this is normal and acceptable or that no I am doing
>   things unacceptably.

It is perfectly acceptable to add other things to the context in your views (otherwise, how would you render things?).

The problem comes when you are talking about *form logic*, and here is where there are some issues with your code/approach.

There is a convention in django (which you are free to violate), is that forms go in a `forms.py` file that is part of your application.

You can perfectly declare all your form classes in your `views.py`, there is nothing wrong with this approach but once you start collaborating with others, or start combining public django apps into your code, it is best to use a convention.  After all, a software development framework is nothing but a bunch of *conventions* and some helpers all bundled together nicely.

However, a more serious problem with your logic is that you are not using form validation - and this you must **absolutely stop right now**.

Forms are - at their core - a way to validate *dictionaries*, and they are one of the most powerful features of the django framework. They allow you to validate *any* dictionary and are used anywhere you are working with models or data.

The code you have written is almost exactly what the form validation does - it checks if required fields are missing in the form (or, think of another way - required keys are None in the dictionary) and then adds error messages and marks the form (or dictionary) as invalid.

The basic logic of using forms is like this:

```
def someview(request):
    form = SomeForm()  # This creates an unbound (empty) form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  # Bind the form to
                                                      # POST data
        if form.is_valid():
           # perform validation
           # do something with form's data

           data = form.cleaned_data['somefield']

           # Or, if its a model form (a form that is tied to a
           # model), save the model since the form is validated
           obj = form.save()

           # All post requests should redirect
           return redirect('index')
        else:
           # The form was not valid, return the form
           # to the view, except this time it will
           # contain helpful error messages
           return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
     else:
           # Return an empty form to the view
           # for the user to fill in, as this is a GET not POST
           # request
           return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

You can always customize the validation rules for a form either on a field-by-field basis, or on the overall data in the form. This is discussed in the documentation on [form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/).

> Off-hand there looks like some non DRY boilerplate if I do this in
>   each view that needs a form.

The new CBV have solved this problem by taking care of the repeated logic (one of the benefits of inheritance and classes). The code I pasted above can be minimized to the following when using [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class SomeView(FormView):
    template_name = 'form.html'
    form_class = SomeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data['somefield']
        return super(SomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

> There also appears to be some debate in the blogs & tutorials for form
>   logic. Its hard to tell whether modifying a CBV or using some good ol'
>   FBV is preferred. I just don't want to get any bad habits while I am
>   still new and learning.

There is nothing wrong with using FBV - they are still perfectly valid django. The benefit you get with CBV is that common functionality is only written once. My advice is to use CBV when you have common logic that you want to modify on a per-view basis. Forms is a good example, displaying models, pagination, rendering simple templates, downloading data (for example, you can have one base view that converts objects to Excel, and then inherit from here in any view that needs to provide a download feature) are good candidates for CBV.

Comment: This is a great response and he should certainly put your suggestions to use. However, I think he was more concerned about having a view with a bunch of other context data such as `all_sliders`, `all_marketing`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers Burkhan, I actually do have a class in forms.py.  As you point out though I was not using that class correctly.  It's a good thing you guys stopped me before I made too much of a mess.